# How can I check a value in a cell in an array Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I want to calculate how many Y's & N's appear in an array / range defined:

Cell Range: `D4:D42`

```
function myFunction() {
 var count = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(5, 3, 40, 1);
 var numRows = count.getNumRows();
 var numCols = count.getNumColumns();
 var y = 0;
 var n = 0;

 for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
   var currentValue = count.getCell(i, j).getValue();
   if (currentValue = "y") {
    y = y + 1;
   } else if (currentValue = "n") {
    n = n + 1;
   }
  }
 }
 Browser.msgBox("There are " + y + " paid & " + n + " not paid");
}
```

This returns 40 Y's and 0 N's

Not sure what I am doing wrong here but I think it's a simple fix!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Excel, I have removed the tag.  Please read the descriptions before just adding the tag because it is suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
if (currentValue = "y") {
```

You are assigning "y" to currentValue. To actually check for equality, you should try the "===" operator. Try this and see if it solves your problem:

```
function myFunction() {
    var count = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(5, 4, 39, 1);
    var numRows = count.getNumRows();
    var numCols = count.getNumColumns();
    var y = 0;
    var n = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
            var currentValue = count.getCell(i, j).getValue();
            if (currentValue === "y") {
                y = y + 1;
            } else if (currentValue === "n") {
                n = n + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    Browser.msgBox("There are " + y + " paid & " + n + " not paid");
}
```

I also updated the getRange() parameters to match D4:D42. In your code, they matched C5:C44. See the [getRange() function documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.

I knew it was something obvious. I know the parameters were off, I realised after I posted the code - I adjusted it in my own one :-)